# Is There any way to achieve a ZeroMQ fullduplex channel?

Tags: c#, python, zeromq

The project is to build a messaging mechanism between a Python and C# program via ZeroMQ .

I want messages to be able to travel in/out from both ends at any time, which is NOT a basic request-reply model a.k.a. **`REQ/REP`**.
One way I can think of is to build a **`PUB/SUB`** model on two ports, i.e. two one way channels.
Is there any method to get a real duplex channel?

Comment: Will there be a single instance of each program?  (Eg, a single Python process communicating w/ a single C# process).

Comment: @colini yes,there are two process: one python,one c#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this with ZeroMQ.  I suggest using a DEALER/ROUTER socket pair:

- Choose one program to be the "server", the other the "client".
- The server will bind a ROUTER socket on a port.
- The client will connect a DEALER socket to the server's ROUTER port.
  (Note: this implies that the client must know the server's IP and port in advance.)

At this point the client can send messages to the server, but the server has no way to send to the client.

- The client sends a "HELLO" message to the server.

The server will receive a message that includes the client's address and the HELLO message.  Now the server can send messages to the client using the client's address.

DEALER/ROUTER is considered an "advanced" socket pair in ZeroMQ.  My description here is very high level.  You'll really need to read [the docs](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc66) to get the most out of ZeroMQ.

Answer (score 1):

### Oh yes, Sir!

Use the **`PAIR-PAIR`** or even the **`XREQ-XREP`** ought make it.

The best next step is to carefully read the respective Scalable Formal Communication Pattern archetypes' access-points' API documentation, so as to cross-check, that all pieces of pre-wired behavioural logic meet your Project needs and voilá, harness them in your messaging setup and tune-up the settings so as to meet you performance and latency needs.

That is this simple ( thanks to all the genuine knowhow hidden in these builtins ).

Using for years this very sort of inter-platforms integration among Python + C/MQL4 and other computing nodes, so well worth one's time to learn the powers and strengths of ZeroMQ.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.But I can only found **XPUB-XSUB** rather than **XREQ-XREP** according to official tutorial. And XPUB has also been limited to duplex messaging(i.e msg cannot go from SUB to PUB). As for PAIR, guide indicates that it is more like a inter-process strategy.

Comment: FYI: if you check the #include's #define-s, the XREQ/XREP == DEALER/ROUTER

Comment: The one thing I don't understand is why it's so complicated to do the simplest thing.

Comment: @cubuspl42 Once you spend some time designing smart and performant distributed applications, you would consider ZeroMQ very smart and very simple, if comparing apples to apples ( attempts to design as fast, as flexible, as universal, as robust MQ-s show, that neither gets as far as ZeroMQ and/or nanomsg have got, so ... seems I missed your comment's point )

Comment: @user3666197 I'm trying to implement an distributed mutual exclusion algorithm with ZMQ (it's an academic task). There are only 3 types of message, REQUEST, REPLY and RELEASE. The last one does not need a reply. So it _nearly_ fits REQ/REP. I could go with a REQ/REP + PUB/SUB pair, but correct me if I'm wrong, I will lose FIFO guarantee if I go down that road. So actually the simplest non-constrained fullduplex channel would work for me, but it's not there in ZMQ. I don't understand it.

Comment: I can see that you guys suggest DEALER/ROUTER, but from the docs it doesn't seem to be designed with a non-constrained fullduplex channel in mind. I will keep trying wrapping my head around that.

Comment: @cubuspl42 Not sure **whom do you call " *you guys* ".** Feel free to post an MCVE-formulated question with all details relevant to your case, if you try ask StackOverflow Community Members for some help with a design that ought work as per specification.

Comment: By you guys I mean you and @colini, because you both recommend DEALER/ROUTER solution, which seems to be an advanced/DIY combination in ZMQ. I'm commenting here, because I believe that my problem is nearly the same as the OP's. I don't understand why the answer, although you call it simple, seems complex and hacky, while the problem seems the simplest of all possible in this field. Maybe it's because I'm missing the bigger picture.

Comment: Like you suggested, I've posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49467333/can-reply-be-optional-in-zeromq