# Can reply be optional in ZeroMQ?

Tags: java, c, network-programming, zeromq, distributed-computing

I'm implementing a [Lamport's distributed MUTEX algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_distributed_mutual_exclusion_algorithm) in ZeroMQ.

> **Algorithm :**
>
> **Requesting process**
>
> 1 ) Pushing its request in its own queue (ordered by time stamps)
>       2 ) Sending a request to every node.
>       3 ) Waiting for replies from all other nodes.
>       4 ) If own request is at the head of its queue and all replies have been received, enter critical section.
>       5 ) Upon exiting the critical section, remove its request from the queue and send a release message to every process.
>
> **Other processes**
>
> 1 ) After receiving a request, pushing the request in its own request queue (ordered by time stamps) and reply with a time stamp.
>       2 ) After receiving release message, remove the corresponding request from its own request queue.

I'm considering coding the solution in C or Java, but the core of the problem seems to be language-neutral.

In my problem, I have three message types, let's call them `Request`, `Reply` and `Release`. The `Request`/`Reply` messages fit well into REQ/REP pattern, but the `Release` message is one-way signal and does not need a reply. I could add an additional PUB/SUB pair, but then, in my understanding, I will not have the guarantee of FIFO delivery order in the system, because I would end up having two concurrent TCP connections (is this assumption right?).

I could make use of a basic non-constrained fullduplex channel. Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623187/is-there-any-way-to-achieve-a-zeromq-fullduplex-channel) suggests using DEALER/ROUTER pair, but it seems like an overkill for such a simple problem. In docs, DEALER/ROUTER is described in [Advanced Request-Reply Patterns](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#advanced-request-reply) chapter, and my problem doesn't seem to need an extreme solution.

How can my problem be solved?

Comment: Please fill free to suggest a better title.

Comment: You have been a member for a very long time, and have asked enough questions and answered enough answers to know better than to post such broad questions. For starters, Java *or* C? Pick *one*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The Java/C problem is not the worst part - ZeroMQ has native C interface and a good [Java] port. I can accept solutions with potential snippets in any of these languages. I also fill (a bit) bad about the broadness of the question, but I didn't know how to narrow it down without creating an XY problem. I've shared the context, I've provided what I've tried before, I've linked a related question. I believe that the question is acceptable, but I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: @user3666197 Thanks for copying and pasting the algorithm description, but I hoped that I formed the essence of the problem I'm facing. The link was only for the curious. Now this is on edge of being closed down as a homework question.

Answer (score 1):

> "*Can **reply** be optional in ZeroMQ?*"

### Short version: Can.

just set properly **`.setsockopt( zmq.REQ_RELAXED, 1 )`**

---

### Longer version:

There will be more issues yet to be solved for defined problem, if indeed distributed-system ought gain robustness. **`REQ/REP`** need not fall into a principally unsalvageable mutual-deadlock, as a distributed-FSA was shortcut with `.REQ_RELAXED` settings, yet ZeroMQ does not provide warranty for a message delivery. It is a best-effort delivery, so you need to implement a higher-level protocol handshaking, if in a need for a guaranteed message delivery.
Setting **`.setsockopt( zmq.REQ_CORRELATE, 1 )`** may help in this.

Comment: Can't I rely on retransmission on TCP layer?

Comment: Forget about low level details, these are well handled by all the available ZeroMQ transport-class engines  ( not only tcp:// ... ) - the Zen-of-Zero principle simply goes with a just-enough functionality and leaves services smart-enough for low-latency and high-performance. Users with needs above these Zen-of-Zero can yet add additional surplus overheads, as the robust-delivery, distributed-consensus and many others require, so it is your turn to add ad-hoc layers as you need 'em. **That is both smart and fair, isn't it?**

Comment: Quoting the docs: "When set to 1, sending another message is allowed and has the effect of disconnecting the underlying connection to the peer from which the reply was expected, triggering a reconnection attempt on transports that support it.". Doesn't seem like a lightweight first-class solution. :(

Comment: Native API 4.2+ does not state anything like that, sorry.

Comment: You are right, it changed between 4.0 and 4.2. Interesting.

Comment: I'm nearly satisfied with this solution. Perfectly, there could be a way of tunnelling a REQ/REP and a PUB/SUB virtual channels inside one common channel, for the sake of message ordering. But I guess `REQ_RELAXED` is good enough.